# Fetch, plot, and send security incident statistics with Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, statistics, data-visualization

**TLDR:** I don't develop for a living. If someone could point me in the right direction to make my script more readable/pythonic I would appreciate the assistance.

In particular I'm struggling with the charts found in `makeCharts()` and code-flow throughout.

I have tried writing `makeCharts()` section as a for loop `for workbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"}) as piechart`, but received a `_exit error` which I guess makes sense as I'm not writing till the end of the function.

**Background**: We use a Security Incident Response Platform which has a available API but somewhat awful reporting. To offset this I have been writing a personal project script while learning pandas which pulls the last 30/60/90 day case metrics and creates some charts. The below is my current complete script sans identifying information.

**Objectives:** I really have been struggling to make this script:

A) More Pythonic (specifically `makeCharts()` and `main()`).

B) Faster I timed it at 42seconds across 350+ entries, which leads me to believe my `main()` loop could be improved.

C) Easier to read code-flow in the process of addressing the above.

```
# imports
# defined globals

start = time.time()
def main(api):
    # Finds all cases on SIRP endpoint
    # Creates all30, all60, all90 dictionaries from epoch
    all30, all60, all90 = {}, {}, {}
    response = api.find_cases(range="all", sort=[])

    def addToDict(arg, response, i):
        arg[(i)] = {
            "Name":
            response.json()[i]["title"],
            "ID":
            response.json()[i]["id"],
            "Owner":
            response.json()[i]["owner"],
            "Severity":
            response.json()[i]["severity"],
            "Created": (time.strftime(
                "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                time.gmtime(response.json()[i]["createdAt"] / 1000.0)))
        }
        if 'endDate' in response.json()[i]:
            arg[(i)].update({
                "Closed": (time.strftime(
                    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                    time.gmtime(response.json()[i]["endDate"] / 1000.0))),
                "Resolution":
                response.json()[i]["resolutionStatus"]
            })
        return

    if response.status_code == 200:
        i = 0
        while i < len(response.json()):
            if (response.json()[i]["createdAt"] / 1000) > time.mktime(
                (datetime.date.today() -
                 datetime.timedelta(days=30)).timetuple()):
                addToDict(all30, response, i)
            if (response.json()[i]["createdAt"] / 1000) > time.mktime(
                (datetime.date.today() -
                 datetime.timedelta(days=60)).timetuple()):
                addToDict(all60, response, i)
            else:
                addToDict(all90, response, i)
            i += 1
    makeSS(all30, all60, all90)


def makeSS(all30, all60, all90):
    # creates (4) dataframes in pandas
    # all30/df1 - 30day dataframe from all30 dict
    # all60/df2 - 60day dataframe from all60 dict
    # all90/df3 - 90 day dataframe from all90 dict
    # df4 - separate sheet for chart data
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        all30,
        index=['Created', 'Severity', 'Owner', 'Name', 'Closed',
               'Resolution']).transpose()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        all60,
        index=['Created', 'Severity', 'Owner', 'Name', 'Closed',
               'Resolution']).transpose()
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(
        all90,
        index=['Created', 'Severity', 'Owner', 'Name', 'Closed',
               'Resolution']).transpose()
    df4 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Created': (df1.count()['Created']),
        'Closed': (df1.count()['Closed']),
        'Owner': (df1['Owner'].value_counts().to_dict()),
        'Resolution': (df1['Resolution'].value_counts().to_dict()),
        'Severity': (df1['Severity'].value_counts().to_dict())
    })
    makeCharts(df1, df2, df3, df4)


def makeCharts(df1, df2, df3, df4):
    # create pie charts, xlsx and save locally
    with pd.ExcelWriter("foo.xlsx",
                        engine="xlsxwriter",
                        options={"strings_to_urls": False}) as writer:
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Summary Charts")
        worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)
        piechart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"})
        piechart.set_title({'name': 'New vs. Closed Cases'})
        piechart.set_style(10)
        piechart.add_series({
            'name': 'Open vs. Closed Cases Last 30',
            'categories': '=Tracking!$B$1:$C$1',
            'values': '=Tracking!$B$2:$C$2',
        })
        worksheet.insert_chart("D2", piechart, {
            'x_offset': 25,
            'y_offset': 10
        })
        piechart1 = workbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"})
        piechart1.set_title({'name': 'Severities'})
        piechart1.set_style(10)
        piechart1.add_series({
            'name': 'Severity Last 30',
            'categories': '=Tracking!$A$2:$A$4',
            'values': '=Tracking!$F$2:$F$4',
        })
        worksheet.insert_chart("M2", piechart1, {
            'x_offset': 25,
            'y_offset': 10
        })
        piechart2 = workbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"})
        piechart2.set_title({'name': 'Resolution Last 30'})
        piechart2.set_style(10)
        piechart2.add_series({
            'name': 'Resolution Last 30',
            'categories': '=Tracking!$A$5:$A$6',
            'values': '=Tracking!$E$5:$E$6',
        })
        worksheet.insert_chart("D19", piechart2, {
            'x_offset': 25,
            'y_offset': 10
        })
        piechart3 = workbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"})
        piechart3.set_title({'name': 'Case Ownership Last 30'})
        piechart3.set_style(10)
        piechart3.add_series({
            'name': 'Case Ownership Last 30',
            'categories': '=Tracking!$A$7:$A$10',
            'values': '=Tracking!$D$7:$D$10',
        })
        worksheet.insert_chart("M19", piechart3, {
            'x_offset': 25,
            'y_offset': 10
        })
        df1.to_excel(writer,
                     sheet_name="Cases newer than 30 Days",
                     startrow=1,
                     header=False)
        formatSS((writer.sheets["Cases newer than 30 Days"]), workbook, df1)
        df2.to_excel(writer,
                     sheet_name="Cases older than 60 days",
                     startrow=1,
                     header=False)
        formatSS((writer.sheets["Cases older than 60 days"]), workbook, df2)
        df3.to_excel(writer,
                     sheet_name="Cases older than 90 days",
                     startrow=1,
                     header=False)
        formatSS((writer.sheets["Cases older than 90 days"]), workbook, df3)
        df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Tracking")
    writer.save()
    send()


def formatSS(worksheet, workbook, arg):
    # add width to columns, filter, freeze
    worksheet.set_column("A:A", 3.5, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.set_column("B:B", 17.25, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.set_column("C:C", 10, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.set_column("D:D", 10, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.set_column("E:E", 100, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.set_column("F:F", 17.25, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.set_column("G:G", 11.25, workbook.add_format())
    worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0)
    worksheet.autofilter("A1:G100")
    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        "bold": True,
        "text_wrap": True,
        "valign": "top",
        "fg_color": "#CCCCCC",
        "border": 1,
    })
    for col_num, value in enumerate(arg.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
    return worksheet, workbook


def send():
    # send the created xlsx
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = "Address@Domain.com"
    msg["To"] = sendTo
    msg["Subject"] = "Metrics"
    msg.attach(
        MIMEText("Attached are the requested case metrics in .XLSX format."))
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open("Foo.xlsx", "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header("Content-Disposition",
                    'attachment; filename="Foo.xlsx"')
    msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.sendmail(msg["From"], [msg["To"]], msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()


main(api)
print('It took', time.time() - start, 'seconds.')
exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex refactoring/improvements:

Involved *Refactoring* techniques: **Rename variable**, **Rename function**, **Extract variable**, **Extract function**, **Substitute Algorithm**, **Slide statements**, **Split phase** (well-known classics https://refactoring.com/catalog/) + eliminating duplication and rearranging responsibility

Completely different OOP approach to your script, representing `SIRPPipeline` (*SIRP* Pipeline) which is initialized with passed `api` component/client, composed and running as a set of consecutive operations/phases:
 
*loading data | making dataframes | making/building charts | send email*.

In more details:

- **`loading data`**. Covered by instance method `_load_data` which initiates API call to fetch the crucial source data and, if successful, populates target days dictionaries with records data (method `_fill_day_dicts`)
- **`making dataframes`**. Covered by method `make_dataframes` which has a concrete single responsibility: construct 4 crucial dataframes (*30 days, 60 days, 90 days, counts*)
- **`making/building charts`**. Covered by complex method `make_charts`. It initiates `ExcelWriter` object, declares inner functions for internal usage: `_insert_pie_chart` (builds and inserts pie chart to specified worksheet) and `_df_days_to_excel` (writes passed dataframe to *writer* object). `_set_workbook_layout` method establishes workbook/worksheet layout/format and saves it to worksheet.
- **`send email`**. Static method `send_email` builds and sends an email related to "case metrics" pipeline event. The old function `send` was too generalized while `send_email` method reflects concrete purpose in scope of pipeline.

---

```
import datetime
import smtplib
import time
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import pandas as pd


class SIRPPipeline:
    TIME_FMT = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    DF_INDEX = ['Created', 'Severity', 'Owner', 'Name', 'Closed', 'Resolution']

    def __init__(self, api):
        """Security Incident Response Platform prosessing pipeline.
           Accepts API object on initialization phase.
        """
        self._api = api
        self._all30_dict = {}
        self._all60_dict = {}
        self._all90_dict = {}

        self._df_30days = None
        self._df_60days = None
        self._df_90days = None
        self._df_counts = None
        self._dataset = None

    def _load_data(self):
        # Finds all cases on SIRP endpoint
        self._api_response = self._api.find_cases(range="all", sort=[])

        if self._api_response.status_code == 200:
            self._dataset = self._api_response.json()
            self._fill_day_dicts()

    @staticmethod
    def _add_record(days_dict, record, key):
        days_dict[key] = {
            "Name": record["title"],
            "ID": record["id"],
            "Owner": record["owner"],
            "Severity": record["severity"],
            "Created": (time.strftime(
                SIRPPipeline.TIME_FMT,
                time.gmtime(record["createdAt"] / 1000.0)))
        }
        if 'endDate' in record:
            days_dict.update({
                "Closed": (time.strftime(
                    SIRPPipeline.TIME_FMT,
                    time.gmtime(record["endDate"] / 1000.0))),
                "Resolution": record["resolutionStatus"]
            })

    def _fill_day_dicts(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()

        for i, record in enumerate(self._dataset):
            if (record["createdAt"] / 1000) > time.mktime(
                    (today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).timetuple()):
                self._add_record(self._all30_dict, record, key=i)

            elif (record["createdAt"] / 1000) > time.mktime(
                    (today - datetime.timedelta(days=60)).timetuple()):
                self._add_record(self._all60_dict, record, key=i)

            else:
                self._add_record(self._all90_dict, record, key=i)

    def make_dataframes(self):
        """Creates (4) pandas dataframes:
        - df_30days dataframe from all30 dict
        - df_60days dataframe from all60 dict
        - df_90days dataframe from all90 dict
        - df_counts - separate sheet for chart data
        """
        self._df_30days = pd.DataFrame(self._all30_dict, index=SIRPPipeline.DF_INDEX).transpose()
        self._df_60days = pd.DataFrame(self._all60_dict, index=SIRPPipeline.DF_INDEX).transpose()
        self._df_90days = pd.DataFrame(self._all90_dict, index=SIRPPipeline.DF_INDEX).transpose()
        self._df_counts = pd.DataFrame({
            'Created': (self._df_30days.count()['Created']),
            'Closed': (self._df_30days.count()['Closed']),
            'Owner': (self._df_30days['Owner'].value_counts().to_dict()),
            'Resolution': (self._df_30days['Resolution'].value_counts().to_dict()),
            'Severity': (self._df_30days['Severity'].value_counts().to_dict())
        })

    @staticmethod
    def _set_workbook_layout(workbook, worksheet, df):
        # add width to columns, filter, freeze
        worksheet.set_column("A:A", 3.5, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.set_column("B:B", 17.25, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.set_column("C:C", 10, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.set_column("D:D", 10, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.set_column("E:E", 100, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.set_column("F:F", 17.25, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.set_column("G:G", 11.25, workbook.add_format())
        worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0)
        worksheet.autofilter("A1:G100")

        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            "bold": True,
            "text_wrap": True,
            "valign": "top",
            "fg_color": "#CCCCCC",
            "border": 1,
        })

        for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values, 1):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

    def make_charts(self):

        def _insert_pie_chart(wbook, wsheet, title, cell_pos, series):
            piechart = wbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"})
            piechart.set_title({'name': title})
            piechart.set_style(10)
            piechart.add_series(series)
            wsheet.insert_chart(cell_pos, piechart, {
                'x_offset': 25,
                'y_offset': 10
            })

        def _df_days_to_excel(writer, sheet_name, df_days):
            df_days.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, header=False)
            self._set_workbook_layout(writer.book, (writer.sheets[sheet_name]), df_days)

        # create pie charts, xlsx and save locally
        with pd.ExcelWriter("foo.xlsx",
                            engine="xlsxwriter",
                            options={"strings_to_urls": False}) as writer:
            workbook = writer.book
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Summary Charts")
            worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)

            _insert_pie_chart(workbook, worksheet, title='New vs. Closed Cases', cell_pos='D2', series={
                'name': 'Open vs. Closed Cases Last 30',
                'categories': '=Tracking!$B$1:$C$1',
                'values': '=Tracking!$B$2:$C$2',
            })
            _insert_pie_chart(workbook, worksheet, title='Severities', cell_pos='M2', series={
                'name': 'Severity Last 30',
                'categories': '=Tracking!$A$2:$A$4',
                'values': '=Tracking!$F$2:$F$4',
            })
            _insert_pie_chart(workbook, worksheet, title='Resolution Last 30', cell_pos='D19', series={
                'name': 'Resolution Last 30',
                'categories': '=Tracking!$A$5:$A$6',
                'values': '=Tracking!$E$5:$E$6',
            })
            _insert_pie_chart(workbook, worksheet, title='Case Ownership Last 30', cell_pos='M19', series={
                'name': 'Case Ownership Last 30',
                'categories': '=Tracking!$A$7:$A$10',
                'values': '=Tracking!$D$7:$D$10',
            })

            _df_days_to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Cases newer than 30 Days", df_days=self._df_30days)
            _df_days_to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Cases older than 60 days", df_days=self._df_60days)
            _df_days_to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Cases newer than 90 Days", df_days=self._df_90days)

            self._df_counts.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Tracking")
            writer.save()

    @staticmethod
    def send_mail():
        # send_mail the created xlsx
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg["From"] = "Address@Domain.com"
        msg["To"] = send_to  # consider `send_to` declaration
        msg["Subject"] = "Metrics"
        msg.attach(
            MIMEText("Attached are the requested case metrics in .XLSX format."))
        part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open("Foo.xlsx", "rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header("Content-Disposition",
                        'attachment; filename="Foo.xlsx"')
        msg.attach(part)
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)  # consider `smtp_server` declaration
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.sendmail(msg["From"], [msg["To"]], msg.as_string())
        smtp.quit()

    def run(self):
        self._load_data()
        self.make_dataframes()  # may be protected
        self.make_charts()      # may be protected
        self.send_mail()


def main(api):
    pipe = SIRPPipeline(api)
    pipe.run()


# api initialization
# ...
start = time.time()
main(api)
print('It took', time.time() - start, 'seconds.')
exit()
```

As for time performance, it requires an appropriate testable sample data for realistic measurements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this well thought out answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ImNotLeet, you're welcome. It's great if it's helped you to find the "way".